# Why do my models return 0 when accessing a string-based primary key model property in Laravel 4?

Tags: string, laravel-4, primary-key

I have a table set up something like this:

```
Schema::create('capability', function($T) {
    $T->string('code',32)->primary();
    $T->string('name',64);
});
```

And a corresponding model like this:

```
class Capability extends BaseModel {
    protected $table = 'capability';
    protected $primaryKey = 'code';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

When I seed some data like this...

```
$c1 = Capability::create(array(
    'name'  => 'Manage Clients',
    'code'  => 'manage_clients'
));
```

...and access the data members of $c1 like this...

```
echo $c1->name.", ".$c1->code;
```

...the result is `Manage Clients, 0`.

Why is the result not `Manage Clients, manage_clients` as I was expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `public $incrementing = false` to the model class.